# HTML/CSS dropdown menu not overlaying or displaying in block

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Having some trouble getting my dropdown menu to display properly on hover; it's currently displaying all on one line and also appears not to be overlaying, despite z-index being set to 1. Played around with making projects a p, a, and div but still stumped. Any advice?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="/" id="name-link">Name</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a>Projects</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/">Project 1</a>
                    <a href="/">Project 2</a>
                    <a href="/">Project 3</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <a href="/about.html">About</a>
        <a href="/">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .015em;
    color: #000000;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    color: #a9c4d4;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 110px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

#name-link {
    color: #a9c4d4;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.selected-link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/29gev50b/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the css of "dropdown-content". The position absolute does that thing. remove this position absolute css from "dropdown-content" and it will work fine.

Comment: Changing this resolved part of the issue: the menu now displays in block and is situated properly under "projects." However, the menu still does not overlay the rest of the navbar and main content div. It also pushes the rest of the nav link text to the right when the menu is expanded.

Comment: remove overflow:hidden for .navbar. And add top:70px (you can put any value for top, as your design need), background: #ddd (put your desire background color.). hope it will solve all the issues. 
note: for these changes, do not remove position absolute for "dropdown-content".

Comment: this worked! although i'll note i added top:70px to .dropdown-content rather than .navbar

Answer (score 0):

You did not leave enough room in your `navbar` div container for the expansion of the menu which is why it gets cut off. `z-index` won't work because the box (div) isn't large enough.

Add `min-height: 100px;` to your `navbar` to fix.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .015em;
  color: #000000;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #a9c4d4;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 110px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#name-link {
  color: #a9c4d4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.selected-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="/" id="name-link">Name</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a>Projects</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="/">Project 1</a>
        <a href="/">Project 2</a>
        <a href="/">Project 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/about.html">About</a>
    <a href="/">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```